# data constructor used without argument in pattern?

Tags: compiler-errors, sml, smlnj

I'm not that familiar with SML but I have wrote the following program:

```
datatype 'a bin_tree = Leaf of 'a
|   Node of 'a bin_tree * 'a bin_tree

fun height Leaf (x) = 0
|   height Node (l1,l2) = 1 + Int.max(l1,l2)

fun is_balanced Leaf (x) = true
|   is_balanced Node (l1,l2) = 
    if(abs(height(l1) - height(l2))<2)
        then (is_balanced(l1); is_balanced(l2))
    else false

val prod_tree = fold_tree
    op* (fn x => x)

fun fold_tree e f Leaf (x) =  f(x)
|   fold_tree e f Node (l1, l2) = (e(fold_tree e f(l1)), e(fold_tree e f(l2)))
```

However, when the is compiled `use "lab2.sml";` I get the following error:

```
lab2.sml:4.12-4.16 Error: data constructor Leaf used without argument in pattern
lab2.sml:5.10-5.14 Error: data constructor Node used without argument in pattern
lab2.sml:7.17-7.21 Error: data constructor Leaf used without argument in pattern
lab2.sml:8.15-8.19 Error: data constructor Node used without argument in pattern
lab2.sml:9.10-9.33 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
```

I've done my research but maybe I'm just missing something. Any help would  be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues. Since this seems to be homework, I'll point out a few things but let you work out the details:

1) In SML, function application has the highest possible precedence. Thus the line

```
fun height Leaf (x) = 0
```

parses as

```
fun (height Leaf) x = 0
```

rather than the intended

```
fun height (Leaf x) = 0
```

Note that `(height Leaf)` has the function `height` applied to the constructor `Leaf` where `Leaf` has no argument -- hence the cryptic error message `data constructor Leaf used without argument in pattern`. You repeat essentially the same error in other places in your code. The solution in all cases is to put parenthesis around the constructor expression; e.g. use `(Leaf x)` rather than `Leaf (x)`.

2) `Int.max(l1,l2)` makes no sense since `l1` and `l2` are trees rather than integers. Probably you meant to take the height of these trees.

3) `;` isn't a Boolean operator. `andalso` is.

4) You are trying to use `fold_tree` before you have defined it. Define it first.

Given these hints you should be able to debug your code. I was able to get your functions working after just a few minutes, so you are almost there.

Comment: Since the `;` operator has type `'a * 'b -> 'b`, surely it is well-defined for booleans. :-P

Comment: @SimonShine Good point. I guess that it would be a Boolean projection operator. I should have said that it isn't a useful Boolean operator (though I'm sure you could come up with a clever use-case).

Comment: Sort of, yes. When testing for side-effects: `val test = (expected_to_fail (...); false) handle ExpectedExn ... => true | _ => false`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll definitely give those suggestions a try